# python signal module, bytecode, asynchronous

Tags: python, asynchronous, interrupt, interrupt-handling

The Python 3.8 documentation for the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/signal.html) states:

> A Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C) signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode instruction).

My understanding is that the Python interpreter when executing a Python program will convert "statements" into bytecode that are machine instructions that can be executed by the processor. My question is: how "small" are the chunks of Python code that get converted into bytecode?

For example:

```
    import signal
    
    token = [None]
    def handle_interrupt(a,b):
        token.pop()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handle_interrupt)

    while True:
        if token:
            print('no interrupt yet!')
            print('proof:',token[0])
        else:
            break
```

If the interpreter enters the if statement, and an interrupt occurs while printing `'no interrupt yet!'`, might we can an IndexError by attempting to access `token[0]` after handle_interrupt is executed, or will the whole `if` block be converted into a single unit of bytecode?

Comment: "into bytecode that are machine instructions that can be executed by the processor." isn't necessarily true. In CPython, code is translated into *Python bytecode*, and that bytecode is interpreted by an interpreter. The produced bytecode doesn't run directly on the CPU.

Comment: If you wrap all your code in a function called `code`, you can do `import dis; print(dis.dis(code))` and see the produced bytecode.

Comment: I see. Is this the recommended way of reasoning about asynchronous events in Python? Would an `asyncio.Lock()` be helpful for suspending execution of the `token.pop()` until the `if` statement finishes?

Comment: `asyncio` is a whole other thing. It isn't simply a library to use whenever you're doing something that's asynchronous. I would say that yes, an `IndexError` is possible here though. Even the single line `print('proof:',token[0])` is made up of at least 6 instructions.